# Building programs with Scons

Tags: macos, deployment, build

I am working on learning how to deploy my applications, I've recently used autotools.
./configure, make, make install

I'd like to use scons but reading the documentation they go over so much but I feel like it's left me right in the middle of a canyon.

If someone can offer some advise as to how to build a simple project. Something more basic than a hello.c example.

Let's say were building cURL: http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.40.0.tar.lzma

Typically with autotools, I'd download, unzip the files, change to the directory
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX
make
sudo make install

That builds the project and puts it into the $PREFIX location

with scons
I should setup an SConstruct file

example:
Program('LIBCURL000', Glob('src/*.c'))

run scons

```
Brother:curl-7.40.0 blubee$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o src/tool_binmode.o -c src/tool_binmode.c
In file included from src/tool_binmode.c:22:
src/tool_setup.h:36:10: fatal error: 'curl_setup.h' file not found
#include "curl_setup.h" /* from the lib directory */
         ^
1 error generated.
scons: *** [src/tool_binmode.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I'm totally lost, and would like some help. I've read through the documentation here: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html but I am still having trouble.

Comment: anyone ever compiled anything with scons, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that SCons cannot find the header file `curl_setup.h` in your example. It is located in the lib directory, so edit your SConstruct file to look more like the following according to [this part of the SCons FAQ](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_get_SCons_to_find_my_.23include_files.3F):

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH='lib')
env.Program('LIBCURL000', Glob('src/*.c'))
```

I am sure there are more steps to be done to get it building, but this should get you through the first issue.

The rest of the [SCons FAQ](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) is a great resource for getting started quickly. Good luck!